# BusinessObjects - DECIMAL->INTEGER in Data Layer

Tags: business-objects

Is it possible that BusinessObject does not allow to make a new attribute by combining two decimal columns in data layer, and then convert the result from DECIMAL to INTEGER?
I am looking IDT and I can't find this...

Comment: By 'combining', do you mean adding them together? If you're doing this in the data layer, this means that the conversion is taking place in the database. Thus, if you want to convert a decimal to an integer, you'd look for a cast or convert function appropriate for the database platform your data is located on.

Comment: That is correct! Thank you very much. I was convinced that I can use only the functions that are listed when you open SQL Editor in IDT. However, bit takeaway for me is that it is also possible to use DATABASE specific functions inside data layer in order to manipulate the data. Thanks once more.

Comment: I'll post my comment as an answer, otherwise the question will stay open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this in the data layer, this means that the conversion is taking place in the database. Thus, if you want to convert a decimal to an integer, you'd look for a cast or convert (database) function appropriate for the database platform your data is located on.